# Inferred type in data declaration

Tags: haskell, type-inference

On several occasions now I have run into trouble when trying to include a monadic action of an inferred type into an existing, explicitly typed data declaration:

```
data Thing = Thing { x :: Int }

t = Thing { x = 42 }

-- action :: m (Maybe (n ())), for some horrendous,
-- deeply parameterized monad transformer stacks m, n

action = return Nothing

data Thing' = Thing' { x :: Int, y :: ? }

t' = Thing' { x = 42, y = action }
```

I don’t want to write down what the complete type of the new field is—in fact, I tried and failed. At most other times I can let the rest of the program inform the type of expressions, and I wish that I could do that here.

I’m surmising that I must give up a lot of compiler type inference support when I include data of such an inferred type in a user-defined data structure. Is that accurate, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I’m surmising that I must give up a lot of compiler type inference support when I include data of such an inferred type in a user-defined data structure. Is that accurate, or am I missing something?

Correct, type inference does not go from usage places to type definitions.

You could parametrise `Thing'` with `y`'s type:

```
data Thing' yType = Thing' { x :: Int, y :: yType }
```

Then compiler would infer `t'`'s type by its usage.

Comment: I expected that might be the standard thing to do. But any other data declarations that have fields of type `Thing'` must now have fields of `Thing' yType`. If I want `yType` inferred I must *also* parameterize *those* declarations.

The compiler's been so accommodating in other situations that this feels kind of unnatural. Maybe it wouldn't if I were more versed in type theory.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Thing' = forall a m. Monad m => Thing' { x:: Int, y :: m a }
```

But you are correct, enabling these language features will make the compiler weaker in some sense, in that type inference is no longer powerful enough to work out the type of something, you will have to add a type ascription, so that the type checker can fill in. Or at least that is how I understand it.